# document.cookie is safe to style the page?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I used the cookie to style the page navigator that is selected by the users.
I used a cookie with localStorage to share cookies on the subdomain. Because localStorage can not be used between domains.

Is my code secure or do you have any suggestions to optimize it?

my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

 var getUserBarPosition;
  if (localStorage.getItem('UserBarPosition') !== null || getCookie('UserBarPosition') !== null) {
    getUserBarPositionCookie = getCookie('UserBarPosition');
    getUserBarPosition = localStorage.UserBarPosition;
    $('body .modami_menu').addClass(getUserBarPositionCookie);
    $('body .modami_menu').addClass(getUserBarPosition);  }


  if (getUserBarPosition == 'user_header_unfix' || getUserBarPositionCookie == 'user_header_unfix') {
  $('body .modami_text-12').addClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');
  $('body #text-13').addClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');
  $('body .userBarPosition').addClass('fa-unlock-alt');
  }

  $('.Mlockicon').on('click', function() {
    if (getUserBarPosition == 'user_header_unfix' || getUserBarPositionCookie == 'user_header_unfix' ) {
      getUserBarPosition = 'user_header_fix';
      getUserBarPositionCookie = 'user_header_fix';
      $('body .modami_menu').addClass('user_header_fix');

$('body .modami_text-12').removeClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');
  $('body #text-13').removeClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');


      $('body .modami_menu').removeClass('user_header_unfix');
      localStorage.setItem('UserBarPosition', 'user_header_fix');
      document.cookie = "UserBarPosition=user_header_fix; domain=.mydomain.com; path=/";

$('body .userBarPosition').removeClass('fa-unlock-alt');

    } else {
      getUserBarPosition = 'user_header_unfix';
      getUserBarPositionCookie = 'user_header_unfix';
      $('body .modami_menu').addClass('user_header_unfix');
$('body .userBarPosition').addClass('fa-unlock-alt');
      $('body .modami_menu').removeClass('user_header_fix');


$('body .modami_text-12').addClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');
  $('body #text-13').addClass('widgetforUnfixedbar');


      localStorage.setItem('UserBarPosition', 'user_header_unfix');
      document.cookie = "UserBarPosition=user_header_unfix; domain=.mydomain.com;  path=/";
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: `Because localStorage can not be used between domains.`
localstorage can be taken by all domain with allowed same origin as google facebook tweeter ... and all API can do. more info https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage

Comment: thanks, using a "documnet.cookie" to style the page is safe?

Comment: i dunno what you try to achieve, but styling a page isn't data private when you accept cross domain as referencing, or add socials script loading with some tag script all you put on you page can be taken by cross domain. Now if you just add a different style chosen by users so you can do what you want, but safe or no safe isn't matter if is just style.